AWS API Gateway Authorizer with cognito + Google
I've set up a user pool and identity pool for Google sign-in in AWS Cognito. User registration and login are functioning correctly, and API Gateway's custom cognito authoriser can validate the ID token issued by Cognito after successful login through user pool method (registering and login). However, after successful Google sign-in by providing id_token (generated by google) in payload, it should generate tokens (access, id and refresh) but instead it is generating AWS temporary credentials. I'm unclear which token should be included in the authorisation header for and how to address the 401 unauthorised error.
i am expecting the cognito tokens in response of google sign in so which i put in headers and my cognito authoriser in api gateway will authorise the token.
this code i am using to exchange the google token (id_token) to cognito credentials :-
def exchange_google_token_for_aws_credentials(id_token: str) -> Dict[str, str]:
    """
    Exchange the Google ID token for AWS temporary credentials using Cognito Identity Pool.
    Returns the Cognito IdentityId (equivalent to UserSub in Cognito).
    """
    try:
        # Get the IdentityId from Cognito Identity Pool
        id_response = cognito_identity_client.get_id(
            IdentityPoolId=IDENTITY_POOL_ID, Logins={PROVIDER_NAME: id_token}
        )
        identity_id = id_response["IdentityId"]

        # Get AWS credentials using the IdentityId
        credentials_response = cognito_identity_client.get_credentials_for_identity(
            IdentityId=identity_id, Logins={PROVIDER_NAME: id_token}
        )

        logger.info(
            f"obtained AWS credentials and IdentityId {identity_id} using Google ID token."
        )
        return {
            "IdentityId": identity_id,  # Cognito IdentityId
            "AccessKeyId": credentials_response["Credentials"]["AccessKeyId"],
            "SecretKey": credentials_response["Credentials"]["SecretKey"],
            "SessionToken": credentials_response["Credentials"]["SessionToken"],
        }
    except ClientError as e:
        logger.error(f"Failed to exchange Google ID token for AWS credentials: {e}")
        raise RuntimeError(
            f"Failed to exchange Google ID token: {e.response['Error']['Message']}"
        )


It's a little bit difficult to follow along what you're trying to do. It sounds like you're calling the cognito Identity Pool with a Google-provided JWT and expecting Cognito-signed JWT etc. - if that's the case, you're calling the wrong service, the user pool can give you a JWT, the identity pool is used exclusively to hand out temporary AWS credentials.
